Compiling LESS on save in VS2022 without project
I want to compile a standalone .less file in Visual Studio 2022, that is not a part of any project, every time the file is being saved (into a .css file with the same name in the same folder). Is there a way to achieve this without creating a dummy project?
I've just tried Web Compiler 2022+. It seems, the extension works for projects only.

After do some researching, looks like no available extensions work for separatee files  detached from VS projects. As a workaround, i would suggest you compile .less files to .css using the command line.
